# iOS Odd Link Behavior

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have an odd problem with links on the following site in iOS:

http://www.bllink.net/aircraftindex.asp

Under the "Galleries" menu, tapping the links under the sub-menus (e.g. "Benny") does nothing. It looks as if Safari is going to navigate to the new page, but then it doesn't.

If you tap and hold, you have the option to open the link in a new tab, as expected, however.

Naturally, the site works fine on desktops.

The DIVs holding the links are NOT set to position:fixed, but to absolute.

Any ideas?

Comment: The links that don't have submenu's work fine for me. Only links with submenu's cause issues.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the onmouseout event of the DIV the link lives on.  If I remove this part:

`onMouseOut="if (document.elementFromPoint(event.x, event.y).id != 'SubAlbum1') document.getElementById('SubAlbum1').style.visibility='hidden' ;"`

the links work correctly, but the DIVs don't vanish on mouseout.

Comment: I was able to work around the issue.  It looks like the navigate request gets cancelled because the DIV that the link lives on is made invisible once it's clicked.  I added a 200ms setTimeout() and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of javascript and use CSS to accomplish a dropdown menu.
This will keep your code much neater and easier to read and your website will be compatible with browsers that have javascript turned off.

You can do this by using the :hover selector in css.

1) So make a list with your menu items or a div containing divs.

2) Hide the submenu's in css by adding: display: none;

3) Use the hover selector to show them on hover. for example:

```
   .menu .menubutton .submenubutton{
      /* selects the div or li within the class menubutton within the class menu */
      display: none;    }    .menu .menubutton:hover .submenubutton{
      /* uses the hover selector on the menubutton, then shows the submenu it contains */
      display: block;    }
```

for an indepth explaination see this article on csswizardry or google for "css dropdown menu":
http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: Positioning can be done by making the menubutton relative and the submenu button absolute. This will give you control over the submenu button by moving it based on the menubuttons position.

Comment: What a slick approach!  FYI, the code in the page you linked needs to be gone over, as transferring it from its old home left some markup garbage in it.

I went ahead and awarded this question to you, although this did not solve the problem.  I was still forced to add the setTimeout command for it to work on my iPhone 4.